# "Powershell"-error while starting a Docker Container with OpenJDK:Windowsservercore

Tags: java, spring, docker

I have developed a Spring application that runs as expectedt. I created a Linux-Docker Container with the application inside the container and could host this in the Azure Cloud.

Now I have a Windows Server which should host the application instead of the Azure Cloud. On this Windows Server I can only use Windows-Docker Containers.

I'm using the following Dockerfile to build the container:

```
FROM openjdk:12.0.1-jdk-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
VOLUME c:/temp
ADD ./target/app.jar app.jar
CMD touch /temp/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","c:\temp\app.jar"]
```

When I want to run the Container I use the following command:

```
docker run -p 80:8080 app:latest
```

Here the error occurs. I receive the following error:

```
At line:1 char:104
+ ... = 'SilentlyContinue'; [java,-jar,c:\temp\app.jar] powershell -Comman ...
+
Unexpected token 'powershell' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo : ParesError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Is my Dockerfile incorrect? Where does the `powershell` comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Could resolve the issue with replacing `ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","c:\temp\app.jar"]` with a cmd command `CMD java -jar c:\app.jar`